# Code deletes entire json file instead of replacing a value

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to create a command that updates a value in a json file however what happens instead is that the entire json file gets deleted expect one profile which is not even the target profile.

jason layout:

```
{"name": "name 1", "trainings": 0, "trainings needed": 10}, {"name": "name 2", "trainings": 0, "trainings needed": 10}, //ect
```

intended output:

```
{"name": "name 1", "trainings": 1, "trainings needed": 10}, {"name": "name 2", "trainings": 0, "trainings needed": 10}, //ect
```

actual output:

{"name": "name 6", "trainings": 0, "trainings needed": 10}

code snipit:

```
@bot.command()
async def add(ctx, a:str):
    a = a.replace("<","")
    a = a.replace(">","")
    a = a.replace("!","")
    a = a.replace("@","")
    member = await bot.fetch_user(a)
    print(member.name)
    
    with open('json_file.json', "r") as f:
      data = json.load(f)
      

    for i in data:

      if i['name'] == member.name:
         i['trainings'] = 1
    with open("json_file.json", "w") as jsonFile:
      json.dump(i, jsonFile)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line should be

```
json.dump(data, jsonFile)
```

Otherwise you are saving the last profile you iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

Your json file should look like this:

```
[
  {"name": "name 1", "trainings": 0, "trainings needed": 10},
  {"name": "name 2", "trainings": 0, "trainings needed": 10},
  ...
]
```

and when you write to `json_file.json`, the first argument should be `data`, not `i`.

```
    with open("json_file.json", "w") as jsonFile:
      # json.dump(i, jsonFile) # incorrect
      json.dump(data, jsonFile)
```